# SQL Order by with Condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

until now i have the following Query:

```
select dl 
from Dienstleistung as dl inner join 
     dl.DienstleistungsOrte as dlo with dlo.ID = :raumID 
order by dl.Bezeichnung
```

Is it possible to order two colums with a condition?

What i want is to order by dl.Bezeichnung and dl.Sortierung. The Condition should be:

```
IF dl.Sortierung = 0 ---> order by dl.Bezeichnung
and
IF dl.Sortierung > 0 --->order by dl.Sortierung
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `dl.Sortierung` can be < 0 or `null`, do:

```
order by case 
    when dl.Sortierung = 0 then dl.Bezeichnung 
    when dl.Sortierung > 0 then dl.Sortierung 
    else SomeOtherColumn 
end
```

else, if `dl.Sortierung` is always >= 0, do

```
order by case 
    when dl.Sortierung = 0 then dl.Bezeichnung 
    else dl.Sortierung 
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE
    WHEN dl.Sortierung = 0 THEN dl.Bezeichnung
    WHEN dl.Sortierung > 0 THEN dl.Sortierung 
  END
```

Or:

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE
    WHEN dl.Sortierung = 0 THEN dl.Bezeichnung
    ELSE dl.Sortierung 
  END
```

Comment: for the second line just use ELSE